Are questions about what research in neuroscience has been done welcome to the Cognitive Sciences SE?
I would like to know what different type of studies have been done on brain processes. One type of question I have in mind is:

has how the brain process X been studied before?
has how the brain does task Y been studied before? What knowledge is out there in this context?

where for a specific example that I think I know is true is X=Image processing since it seems the visual system has been studied and we know about V1,V2,..etc. 
For a more novel task I was interested how the brain processed abstract concepts like mathematics for example and how the brain might to mathematics. So I was curious to know what human type learning has been done for doing that. Is this type of question welcome here? Is research level question welcome to this cite?

Personally, I feel that the following types of questions are off-topic, when no framework or background is given by OP:

Has X been studied?
Is there literature on X?  

With X being a disease / drug interaction / brain processes etc.  
These types of questions are imo off-topic, because they require an extensive literature search for a proper answer, or they can be answered with Yes! Here's a paper Y!'
With Y being the top single paper out of 100k hits on Google Scholar.
The former approach requires hours of work (we're not here to write a review paper for you), the latter can draw in a 100k answers :)
However, with a proper framework, and with background research focusing your question, these types of questions are on-topic and warmly welcomed. For example consider
How do mammals estimate the speed of moving objects? 
Here, OP starts off superbly broad (speed estimation in the visual system), but then focuses the question on a particular process (top-down effects on speed estimation), concluding the question with a specific example. This type of question is great. 

what if X is very specific? where X has probably not been research at all?

@CharlieParker in general, specific questions are great.

I can probably come up with (fairly upvoted) examples of that alas: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/is-it-usually-worthwhile-to-argue-to-try-to-convince-someone
